# App has encountered a problem. The archive C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_251/lib/tools.jar.jar which is referenced by the classpath does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, tools.jar

I have tried adding the tools.jar file manually (as suggested in another question's answer from StackOverflow), but this did not resolve the issue.  This error first occurred with the last update of Java on my laptop.  Any suggestions as to how I would go about eliminating this error message & getting Eclipse to work again?

Comment: What problem were you *originally* trying to solve with this?

Comment: Install and use the JDK, not the JRE.

Comment: unfortunately, using the JDK yielded the same error message @Mark Roffevel

Comment: I was simply trying to run my app as a java application @nitind

Comment: @Casseiopeia Which version of the JDK did you install, and which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the version of the JDK that I had installed is:  14.0.2, and the version of Eclipse is:  Eclipse IDE for Java Developers-2020-06.

Answer (score 0):

The filename is incorrect it should have
.jar
not
.jar.jar

Comment: even so, i had added in a tools.jar file & it still didn't work (per my description)